# sails couldn't read GET parameter from request after angular hashtag

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I tried to integrated sails.js as a route controller and api management, using angular.js as frontend, but I found the problem when using angular to modify URL

For an example /

> Original URL : http://localhost

after modify by $location.search({'lang':destLanguage});

> Modified URL : http://localhost#?lang=fr

Then I am using $window.location.reload(); to reload the page to send the GET parameter to the sails controller, but when I debug at the page controller, I found that sails couldn't read the parameter from request.

> req.param('lang')  == undefined

I am not sure how to solve this issue. I tried to solve these issue for a whole few days.

Thanks,

Comment: If you're using Angular, wouldn't it be better to send a http request to the server in JS, rather than forcibly reloading the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the hash are not query params for the server. It would need to be before the hash, or remove the hash all together.

http://localhost?lang=fr

instead just create function to incorporate into your app

```
var updateLang = function(lang){
 window.location = 'http://localhost?lang=' + lang
}
```

The rest of the answer depends on if your angular is setup to use html5Mode = true. If so, then you can use angular's $location.search() to retrieve your values. If not, then you will need to find a plain javascript to grab that value either on page load or when / where you need it.